# What's the difference between Quantile Plot and Q-Q Plot?

Tags: statistics, data-mining

I am trying to understand the theory behind the Q-Q Plots. So far, I can tell that Q-Q plots are used to plot one univariate quantile distribution against the corresponding quantile values of another univariate quantile distribution.

But then I came across Quantile Plot and the only relevant information given about them is-

- It displays all of the data (allowing the user to assess both the overall behavior and unusual occurrences).
- It plots quantile information
- For a data x<sub>i</sub> data sorted in increasing order, f<sub>i</sub> indicates that approximately 100 f<sub>i</sub>% of the data are below or equal to the value x<sub>i</sub>.

I fail to understand the terms "x<sub>i</sub>", "f<sub>i</sub>", and especially the "100 f<sub>i</sub>%". What are these terms and how is Quantile plot different from Q-Q plot?